# Will MPI_Send block if matching MPI_IRecv takes less data elements?

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, distributed-computing

Assume the following MPI Code.

```
MPI_Comm_Rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

if (rank == 0){
   MPI_Send(a, count, MPI_CHAR, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
   MPI_Send(b, count, MPI_CHAR, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}
else if (rank == 1){
   MPI_IRecv(a, 1, MPI_CHAR, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &req);
   MPI_Recv(b, count, MPI_CHAR, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
   MPI_Wait(&req, &status);
}
```

Is it correct to say the the first `MPI_Send(a, count, ...)` will not block even though its matching `MPI_IRecv(a, 1, ...)` is only reading one element from the buffer?

Also, since no reads/writes are done to buffer `a`, is it correct Process 1 will not block even though `MPI_Wait` is not called directly after `MPI_IRecv`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MPI_Send will block...it is a blocking call. The "blocking" call will return when the send/recv buffer can be safely read/modified by the calling application.  No guarantees are made about the matching MPI_[I]recv call.

The MPI library does not know anything about the read/write status of the buffers in the application.  The MPI standard calls for certain guarantees to be made by the application about the stability of the message buffers.